# Making two pen style in one vector file in QGIS?

Tags: vector, line

I am working with QGIS and I have a vector file of the earth Latitude and longitude [image].
I need to show the horizontal lines as a dash lines and the vertical as a solid line. I am sure that if I make to layer, one horizontal and vertical, it will solve me problem.

However, I wonder is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Can it be done with the Attribute Table?

[image]

Comment: Is there any attribute field that makes difference between the horizontal and vertical lines?

Comment: you should be able to set up a rule in your styling that sets up categories for direction in ('n', 's') and another one for direction in ('e', 'w') - would that work?

Comment: Yes, it solve it. Am I supposed to right done the answer?

Comment: @NitzanMatan If you describe the solution you found as a new answer, it would help future readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for this specific problem, but it should work for other project with the same task.

The first step is to categorized the layers be their direction in the layer styling bar[image]
If you only need to change the color of a line It can be done be clicking on the sub layer in this bar [image]

If you need to change the line pen style mark the sub layer you need to change and then press "change"
 [image]

Now you have more option the change the line style [image]

In order of changing the pen style click on the "Simple line" icon and the Symbol layer type bar will open [image]