# Extricating and sorting data from attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I download shapefile of Alberta from [GEOFABRIK](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada.html) in order to work with the roads shapefile.
The problem was that I get an attribute table with 94,644 rows that was slowing down the computer, additionally to the fact that I get every small road and just the main one as I wanted.

[image]

I looked in the attribute table and found that the road type are classified in the fclass column. As described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246244/making-two-pen-style-in-one-vector-file-in-qgis) I use the categorized function to classify the different road types, so I was able to display only the primary roads.
[image]

Also, it is possible to change the line style, by clicking the "Symbel" bar.
[image]

However, it was only a partial solution, I still have a lot of unnecessary data seem to slowing down me computer.
I was looking for a way to extract the data in need, and to work with this kind of big database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of extricating data I used the "Split vector layer" function.

[image]

I choose the layer I was working on and in the "unique ID field" I choose the fdass column that have the different roads type classification.
[image]

It took some time, but at the end I head diffrent shapefiles for each road type. Know I was able to work only with the road type I needed, and if needed to upload more road layers. It was much easier in compared of working with one big attribute table.